# LESS CSS duplicate class

Tags: css, less

I got a duplicate classes when I inspect my result in chrome.

```
.container .pos-title {
margin-top: 10px;
margin-bottom: 0px;
}
.container .pos-title {
margin-top: 10px;
margin-bottom: 0px;
}
```

why I'm seeing this when I'm just use this in my style.less :

```
.container{
    .panel-body{
        padding: 5px;
    }

    .pos-title{
        margin-top: 10px;
        margin-bottom: 0px;
    }
}
```

Comment: What's your html code?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use `Ctrl+f` find whether you have another similar `CSS` structure defined!

Comment: he did. I declared twice css in my html file, thanks!